# Make images inside two different divs stand in the same place

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm using Wordpress and Woocommerce. I needed a thing which would display the secondary product image as the user hovers on the main one in the shop page. I found an exceptionally good plugin crafted by jameskoster, and I've modified it to my needs. It does what it intends to do, however, I've a glitch which I cannot resolve.

The secondary div is placed below the main one in my actual setup. When the hover happens, everything fine. When the hover vanishes or when I hover over the li element, instead of the a, those things happen:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/9q2h2.jpg

The error is that the secondary image falls below the original div as soon as the hover ends, revealing it and making the transition look bad.

I've past almost the whole yesterday's afternoon trying to fix it. I've tried a lot of things, including height:0; display:none; opacity:0, element positions and several other things, even conditional selectors "~"

However, I can't make it work.
The solution that I need is to make the two divs fit the same spot.
When I hover the actual one, it vanishes and the second appears.

The idea is pretty straightforward. Can you guys help me achieve it?

Comment: Not without seeing the code you are currently using, no.  We can't help.

Comment: Sorry @cale_b, forgot the utmost important part, I'll edit the main post

Comment: If you post a link to ur project i can solve this instantly. But i need to look at your code. NOT* an image of your code.

Answer (score 1):

I've done it with the assistance of Patrick.
The 'flashing' situation was being caused by the:

```
 height :0;
 or display: none;
```

I've implemented the nth-child(1) e (2) solution provided in Patrick's feedback, and made it two things which were of the utmost importance:

```
 position: static;
```

to the first child.
And:

```
position: absolute;
```

to the second child.
That made possible to style the divs and display the images flawlessly in the same location. Then you'll have to adjust the CSS to make the container fit perfectly on your layout.

Answer (score -1):

You need to move the second image into the same wrapper as the first image.

For example you have:

```
<div class="wrapper">
[YOUR IMAGE 1]
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
[YOUR IMAGE 2]
</div>
```

but you want:

```
<div class="wrapper">
[YOUR IMAGE 1]
[YOUR IMAGE 2]
</div>
```

To accomplish this you can use Jquery. Add this to your scripts

```
$('.woocommerce-LoopProduct-link .prod-img-wrap:nth-child(1)').append($('.woocommerce-LoopProduct-link .prod-img-wrap:nth-child(2) img') );
```

If you arent sure how to add this script, you can place it directly into the footer.php like so

```
<script>
(function($){
$('.woocommerce-LoopProduct-link .prod-img-wrap:nth-child(1)').append($('.woocommerce-LoopProduct-link .prod-img-wrap:nth-child(2) img') );
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mwqfL6du/27/

Comment: Hey, @Patrick! Thank you for your answer.
It dind't work, tho. I've included a new .js file into the Wordpress, and the elements look to be completely ignorant towards those rules.